# Can I horizontal filp the UIButton?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, transform

I've some problem with UIButton.

In my case I have to flip the button horizontally.

I tried it's width to minus value. But it doesn't work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply set its `transform` to `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0)`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to rotate 360 degrees horizontally:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75]; // transition speed

[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.YourButton cache:NO];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```